# How to unselect a text for a textfield?

Tags: javascript, css, html

When I make my search form return from a search and display the result, the text query in the textfield is marked as if it were selected text but I don't want it selected:

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3AakF/)

1) What's the best choice the present the search field, should the field be focused or like google when returning from a search, the query string should be on the search field like I've done but google has no focus on the field when returning from a search.

2) How to implement a solution?

What I'm doing now is

```
<input placeholder="Search" name="query" size="20" id="searchtext" title="Search" class="placeholder" alt="q" type="text" value="{{query}}"><script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('searchtext').focus()
</script>
```

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/amf4b/. if you are focusing at any point to lose focus use `.blur()` or set the cursor position at the end of the textfield string.

Comment: @PSL It works. I accept you comment as a working answer.

Comment: Glad it helped u in anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
```

or rather:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```